# Regex Expression for Finding Words Surrounded By {{ }}

Tags: c#, regex

I have a string that has variables inserted within them. They are surround by double curly braces, i.e. `{{VARIABLE}}`.

What Regex expression could be use to return the variable names within the double curly braces?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [lookahead and lookbehind](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/grouping-constructs-in-regular-expressions#zerowidth_positive_lookahead_assertion) assertions to match text that comes after and before certain patterns. You can also use a [negative character class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/character-classes-in-regular-expressions#NegativeGroup) to match characters that aren't `}`, so that your matched string isn't too [greedy](https://medium.com/@wpcarro/non-greedy-regular-expressions-7dfb5177d57e#8d4e).

```
(?<=\{\{)[^}]+(?=\}\})
```

You can see this pattern in action [here](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%28%3f%3c%3d%5c%7b%5c%7b%29%5b%5e%7d%5d%2b%28%3f%3d%5c%7d%5c%7d%29&i=some+text+%7b%7bTag1%7d%7d+more+text+%7b%7btag+2%7d%7d)

Comment: You beat me to it. So here's a link for the OP to test his Regex from here on.
https://regex101.com/r/7hCT3m/1

Answer (score 0):

You could also use a capturing group:

```
\{\{(.+?)}}
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/ySKG5b/1)

If there can not be anything before or after the placeholder and the placeholder itself can contain a { or } you might use:

```
(?<!\S)\{\{(.+?)}}(?!\S)
```

**Explanation**

- `(?<!\S)` Assert what is on the left is not a non whitespace char
- `\{\{` Match {{
- `(.+?)` Capture in group 1 matching any char 1+ times non greedy
- `}}` Match literally
- `(?!\S)` Assert what is on the right is not a non whitespace char

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/ySKG5b/2)